# Using $.data in a foreach jquery not working

Tags: jquery

Currently I am trying to validate multiple forms on a page. In the foreach below the  `$.data(currentFormId, "validator");` never gets hit. States value assigned it not in any execution path. There is a parent function in which this is actually valid.

```
validate: function (options) {
    // if nothing is selected, return nothing; can't chain anyway
    if (!this.length) {
        if (options && options.debug && window.console) {
            console.warn("Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing.");
        }
        return;
    }
    // works ok in this context var validator = $.data(this[0], "validator");

    $("form").each(function (index, value) {
        var currentFormId = 'form#' + $(this).attr('id');
        // check if a validator for this form was already created
        var validator = $.data(currentFormId, "validator");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `var validator = $(this).data("validator")` as `this` is the `form` inside the each?

Comment: Hi, still having the same issue within the ide that values assigned  is not used in any execution path

Comment: Wait. You're just trying to clear an IDE warning? Is it warning you that you aren't actually using the variable "validator" that you are defining here?

Answer (score 0):

$.data() always has this signature: `$.data(element, key, value)`, where element must be the DOM-element you want to get/set data. You have set first argument to `currentFormId` which is a string.

So when you want to set data to a form inside your `.each()`:

```
// set the data named "validator" of the actual form element to 'form#...'
$.data(this, "validator", currentFormId);
```

If you want to retrieve the data named "validator":

```
var valid = $.data(this, "validator"); // --> 'form#...'
```

If you want to get an object with all data assigned to this element:

```
var alldata = $.data(this); // --> Object{validator="form#...", ......}
```

[jQuery.data() Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)